# If $\left(x_n\right)^{1/p}\to0$ then $\left(x_n\right)\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\left(x_n\right)$ be a sequence and $p\in[1,\infty)$. Suppose that $\left(x_n\right)^{1/p}\to0$, is it then true that $\left(x_n\right)\to0$? I know that it must be true, as it is used to prove a number of results; for example, proving that converges in $L^p$ implies convergence in measure. However, I am having trouble proving it. Here is my (incomplete) attempt.

---

Suppose that $\left(x_n\right)^{1/p}\to0$. By definition of converging sequence,

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\,\exists N\in\Bbb N:\text{if }n>N\text{ then } |x_n|^{1/p}<\epsilon.$$

This can be rewritten as,

$$|x_n|<\epsilon^p.$$

Though, I am not really sure if this concludes that $\left(x_n\right)\to0$, since, I figured it is needed that $\left|x_n\right|<\epsilon$. I am probably just missing something trival...

Comment: Instead of $|x_n|^{1/p}<\varepsilon$ take $N$ such that $|x_n|^{1/p}<\varepsilon^{1/p}$

Comment: @leoli1: So simple, I forgot about "messing" with the $\epsilon$ value, thanks!

Comment: WHy not using CONTINUITY of $f(t)=t^p$ at $t=0$?

Comment: Not even that, you still can set $\epsilon^p$ to an arbitrary positive value!

Comment: Embedded assumption is that the inequality holds - is it obvious? When $x_n<1$ you need to be carefully since the root goes up.

Comment: @Moti Irrelevant in this case, since you are not comparing powers of the same positive number